# How to redirect to parent component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redirect, react-router

Hi I'm trying to make a simple CRUD example using React.Js and typescript...

I have the following component hierarchy:

```
-FetchNaselje
--Modal
---AddNaselje
```

AddNaselje is a child of Modal and Modal is child of FetchNaselje, I'm trying to re-render or forcefully update FetchNaselje everytime somebody submits/saves **form** from AddNaselje but I'm having hard time doing that.

I tired passing history of parent and calling it in child like: this.props.history.push("/fetchnaselje"); but nothing happens

this is my routes.tsx file:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Layout } from './components/Layout';
import { Home } from './components/Home';

import { FetchNaselje } from './components/FetchNaselje';
import { AddNaselje } from './components/AddNaselje'; 

export const routes = <Layout>
    <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
    <Route path='/fetchnaselje' component={FetchNaselje} />
    <Route path='/addnaselje(/:nasid)' component={AddNaselje} />
    <Route path='/naselje/edit(/:nasid)' component={AddNaselje} />
</Layout>;
```

This is my parent component code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';
import { Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { AddNaselje } from './AddNaselje';
import { Modal } from './Modal/Modal';

interface FetchNaseljeDataState {
    nasList: NaseljeData[];
    loading: boolean;
    showModal: boolean
    nas_id: number;
}

export class FetchNaselje extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, FetchNaseljeDataState> {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { nasList: [], loading: true, showModal: false, nas_id: -1 };
        fetch('api/Naselje/Index')
            .then(response => response.json() as Promise<NaseljeData[]>)
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({ nasList: data, loading: false });
            });
        // This binding is necessary to make "this" work in the callback  
        this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
        this.handleEdit = this.handleEdit.bind(this);
    }

    public render() {
        let contents = this.state.loading
            ? <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
            : this.renderNaseljeTable(this.state.nasList);
        return <div>
            <h1>Naselje Data</h1>
            <div>This component demonstrates fetching Naselje data from the server.</div>
            <div>
                <Link to="/addnaselje">Create New</Link><br /><br />
                <button type="button" onClick={this.showModal} className="btn">
                    Show Modal
                </button>
                <Modal
                    show={this.state.showModal}>
                    <AddNaselje history={this.props.history} parent={this} />
                </Modal>
            </div>
            {contents}
        </div>;
    }

    showModal = () => {
        this.setState({
            ... this.state,
            showModal: !this.state.showModal
        });
        this.forceUpdate();
    };

    // Handle Delete request for an naselje  
    private handleDelete(id: number) {
        if (!confirm("Do you want to delete naselje with Id: " + id))
            return;
        else {
            fetch('api/Naselje/Delete/' + id, {
                method: 'delete'
            }).then(data => {
                this.setState(
                    {
                        nasList: this.state.nasList.filter((rec) => {
                            return (rec.idnaselje != id);
                        })
                    });
            });
        }
    }
    private handleEdit(id: number) {
        //this.props.history.push("/naselje/edit/" + id);
    }

    // Returns the HTML table to the render() method.  
    private renderNaseljeTable(naseljeList: NaseljeData[]) {
        return <table className='table'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>ID Naselje</th>
                    <th>Naziv</th>
                    <th>Postanski Broj</th>
                    <th>Drzava</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {naseljeList.map(nas =>
                    <tr key={nas.idnaselje}>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>{nas.idnaselje}</td>
                        <td>{nas.naziv}</td>
                        <td>{nas.postanskiBroj}</td>
                        <td>{nas.drzava && nas.drzava.naziv}</td>
                        <td>
                            <a className="action" onClick={(id) => this.handleEdit(nas.idnaselje)}>Edit</a>  |
                            <a className="action" onClick={(id) => this.handleDelete(nas.idnaselje)}>Delete</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                )}
            </tbody>
        </table>;
    }
}
export class NaseljeData {
    idnaselje: number = 0;
    naziv: string = "";
    postanskiBroj: string = "";
    drzava: DrzavaData = { iddrzava: 0, naziv: ""};
    drzavaid: number = 0;
}

export class DrzavaData {
    iddrzava: number = 0;
    naziv: string = "";
}
```

My modal component is like a wrapper with styles set for showing modal window:

```
import * as React from 'react';
const style = require('./style.css');

interface ModaleDataState {
    show: boolean;
}

export class Modal extends React.Component<any, ModaleDataState> {
    render() {

        if (!this.props.show) {
            return null;
        }

        return <div className="modal-background">
            <div className="modal-main">
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
       </div>
    }
}
```

And finally the child component:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';
import { Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { NaseljeData } from './FetchNaselje';
import { DrzavaData } from './FetchNaselje';

interface AddNaseljeDataState {
    title: string;
    loading: boolean;
    drzavaList: Array<any>;
    nasData: NaseljeData;
    drzavaId: number;
}

export class AddNaselje extends React.Component<any, AddNaseljeDataState> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { title: "", loading: true, drzavaList: [], nasData: new NaseljeData, drzavaId: -1 };
        fetch('api/Naselje/GetDrzavaList')
            .then(response => response.json() as Promise<Array<any>>)
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({ drzavaList: data });
            });

        var nasid = -1;
        if (this.props.match) {
            nasid = this.props.match.params["nasid"];
        }

        // This will set state for Edit naselje  
        if (nasid > 0) {
            fetch('api/Naselje/Details/' + nasid)
                .then(response => response.json() as Promise<NaseljeData>)
                .then(data => {
                    this.setState({ title: "Edit", loading: false, nasData: data });
                });
        }
        // This will set state for Add naselje  
        else {
            this.state = { title: "Create", loading: false, drzavaList: [], nasData: new NaseljeData, drzavaId: -1 };
        }
        // This binding is necessary to make "this" work in the callback  
        this.handleSave = this.handleSave.bind(this);
        this.handleCancel = this.handleCancel.bind(this);
    }

    public render() {
        let contents = this.state.loading
            ? <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
            : this.renderCreateForm(this.state.drzavaList);
        return <div>
            <h1>{this.state.title}</h1>
            <h3>Naselje</h3>
            <hr />
            {contents}
        </div>;
    }

    // This will handle the submit form event.  
    private handleSave(event) {

        event.preventDefault();
        const data = new FormData(event.target);
        // PUT request for Edit naselje.  
        if (this.state.nasData.idnaselje) {
            fetch('api/Naselje/Edit', {
                method: 'PUT',
                body: data,
            }).then((response) => response.json())
                .then((responseJson) => {
                    this.props.history.push("/fetchnaselje");
                })
        }
        // POST request for Add naselje.  
        else {
            fetch('api/Naselje/Create', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: data,
            }).then((response) => response.json())
                .then((responseJson) => {
                    this.props.history.push("/fetchnaselje");
                })
        }
        this.props.parent.showModal();
        window.location.reload()
    }

    // This will handle Cancel button click event.  
    private handleCancel(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //this.props.parent.showModal();
        this.props.history.push("/fetchnaselje");
        //this.props.parent.forceUpdate();
    }

    // Returns the HTML Form to the render() method.  
    private renderCreateForm(drzavaList: Array<any>) {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSave} >
                <div className="form-group row" >
                    <input type="hidden" name="idnaselje" value={this.state.nasData.idnaselje} />
                </div>
                < div className="form-group row" >
                    <label className=" control-label col-md-12" htmlFor="Naziv">Naziv</label>
                    <div className="col-md-4">
                        <input className="form-control" type="text" name="naziv" defaultValue={this.state.nasData.naziv} required />
                    </div>
                </div >
                <div className="form-group row">
                    <label className="control-label col-md-12" htmlFor="PostanskiBroj" >Postanski broj</label>
                    <div className="col-md-4">
                        <input className="form-control" name="PostanskiBroj" defaultValue={this.state.nasData.postanskiBroj} required />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group row">
                    <label className="control-label col-md-12" htmlFor="Drzava">Država</label>
                    <div className="col-md-4">
                        <select className="form-control" data-val="true" name="drzavaid" defaultValue={this.state.nasData.drzava ? this.state.nasData.drzava.naziv : ""} required>
                            <option value="">-- Odaberite Državu --</option>
                            {drzavaList.map(drzava =>
                                <option key={drzava.iddrzava} value={drzava.iddrzava}>{drzava.naziv}</option>
                            )}
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div >
                <div className="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-default">Save</button>&nbsp;
                    <button className="btn" onClick={this.handleCancel}>Cancel</button>
                </div >
            </form >
        )
    }
}
```

This props history push doesn't throw any error but it doesn't re render my parent component.

I'm not sure what's the best approach here... please take in consideration that I don't have too much experience in react so I would appreciate if your try to explain the best approach in complete manner not just a short answer... thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My favorite way to re-route in React is to leverage the react-router-dom capabilities (I see you are already using that module).  A simple example is the following (example in JS, but you'll get the idea):

```js
import React, { Fragment } from 'react;
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

class ReRoute extends React.Component {
  state = {
    ...yourState,
    sendToNextPage: false
  }
  
  sendToNext = () => this.setState({ sendToNextPage: true })
  
  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <h1>Your Content....</h1>
        <button onClick={this.sendToNext}>Button to navigate</button>

        {this.state.sendToNextPage &&
          <Redirect to='/path-to-next-page' />
        }
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

There's lots of options surrounding the virtual routing in React, but the above is my favorite because there are several ways to return a  component into your render - which will prompt the redirect.  To me - having that controlled in the state via a boolean is very clear (for yourself and others) on what triggers the redirect, and I'm a fan of the additional capabilities of the Redirect component (see [this](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Redirect))

Comment: I need to be able to redirect programmatically

Comment: @ChenChi I understand what you're saying - but what I propose _is_ navigating programmatically.  The Redirect component doesn't display anything - and it's not exposed to the render() method unless the state boolean changes.  You can choose to `<Redirect to="/path" push />` if you want to push instead of replace in the history module.  It covers your needs.  Another use case is if inside the `{ this.state.sendToNextPage && this.customFunction() }` in that function you could return a <Redirect /> component with all the information you need in the props.

Comment: I tried it but it still doesn't re-instantiate the component as  I want it too... seems like I might need redux for this

Comment: Ok, so again I apologize that I'm not too Typescript savvy - but a couple things I noticed that may help out:
1. Your fetch function I don't believe should be in your constructor (parent) - it should be in componentDidMount() (see React docs).
2. I noticed that you call a function after setting state in showModal().  I'm not sure what this.forceUpdate() is doing - but keep in mind that this function will get called BEFORE the state has returned updated.  If you would like this function to be called AFTER the state returns updated - place it inside the callback `this.setState({}, ()=> fnc())`

Comment: Events in React are synthentic events, so unlike JQuery, the e.preventDefault() is unnecessary (the synthetic event object has a lot of useful date for you to leverage as well so definitely become familiar with that). Finally, (and I hope I'm understanding your issue correctly) I'm not convinced this is a routing issue - I believe you may have an issue "lifting state" (see React docs) and also, anything defined in constructor will not re-render based on state/props changes, but if you have "componentDidMount" logic - this WILL re-render for state/props changes.  Check out "component lifecycle"

Comment: To sum it up - if you need your parent component to re-render based on state changes in the child - you either need to pass a function to the child, that the child can call to make changes to the parent (triggering an update to the parent) OR you need a render prop from the child (part of "lifting state") that signals to the parent what to display based on the child's state.  I do hope I helped some, and please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks for the comments I figured it out now, I had couple mistakes now I extracted fetch into fetchData method and I think the bug was that I didn't put my code inside then function... I will update my answer with the code

Comment: I called the fetchData function from child now it works fine but I wasn't calling it in then at first so it didn't work xD I am n00b with javascript thank you for help

Comment: I accepted your answer because it answers original question but as you said my problem wasn't in redirecting...

Comment: Glad I could help, and glad you got it working!  Thanks.